# Add an item to a group of a PopupMenu dynamically

Tags: java, android, menuitem, popupmenu

I have a **XML menu** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group
        android:id="@+id/orders_filter_messages_group"
        android:checkableBehavior="all">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/orders_filter_messages_channel_1"
            android:title="@string/orders_filter_messages_channel_1" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/orders_filter_messages_channel_2"
            android:title="@string/orders_filter_messages_channel_2" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/orders_filter_messages_channel_3"
            android:title="@string/orders_filter_messages_channel_3" />

    </group>

</menu>
```

I would like to add some items to the **orders_filter_messages_group**, so I did :

```
this.filterMenu = new PopupMenu(this.getActivity(), this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.orders_filter_button));
this.filterMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_orders_filter);

for (Channel channel : channels)
    this.filterMenu.getMenu().add(R.id.orders_filter_messages_group, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, channel.getName());
```

The result is that the items are well added on the PopupMenu, BUT the are added on the end of the list (outside of the group), and consequently, they are not checkable.

If I change the order parameter, I can manage to position them in the right place, but they stay outside of the group and remain uncheckable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getMenu().add()` method returns a MenuItem. With that you get full control...
Try this:

```
MenuItem addedMenuItem = this.filterMenu.getMenu().add(R.id.orders_filter_messages_group, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, channel.getName());
addedMenuItem.setCheckable(true);
```

To access it in the PopupMenu's onClickListener, add a unique ID inside the add() method instead of `Menu.NONE`.

```
final int uniqueID = 12345;
MenuItem addedMenuItem = this.filterMenu.getMenu().add(R.id.orders_filter_messages_group, uniqueID, Menu.NONE, channel.getName());

//and in the onClickListener
filterMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick (MenuItem item) {
                if(item.getItemId() == uniqueID) //TODO
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: It helped me a lot! I also found that this line has the same effect : this.filterMenu.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.orders_filter_messages_group, true, false);